# How to select legend items but still preserve the scale specified by scale_color_manual()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Problem:

I am creating a 2D plot in ggplot. This plot has multiple curves depending on ordered factors. I would like a legend that includes only the first and last factors, and at the same time specify the colors to use for each factor.

---

What I have tried:

Let `colors` be a vector that contains the color specification for each factor. When using `scale_color_manual(values=colors)`, ggplot tries to list in the legend ALL items.

To select only the first and last factors to show in the legend, I went with the recommendation of several answers on StackOverflow: use the `breaks` argument to specify factor value. This worked, but now only the curves relating to the first and last factors had the right colors, the others were grey (ie. `NA` color value).

Any attempt at including two separate `scale_color_manual` failed as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Just set `breaks=` to define the levels you want in the legend and `values=` to define the factor-color relationships.

```
data(iris)

library(ggplot2)

colors <- c("setosa" = "orange", "versicolor" = "red", "virginica" = "purple")
  
ggplot(data = iris) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks = c("setosa", "virginica"), values = colors)
```

[image]